# How do I track the amount of time (in hourly candles) it took for an atr based renko brick to form?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How do I track the amount of time (in hourly candles) it took for an atr based renko brick to form?

I'm trying to counter the number of regular bars per renko brick in pinescript. I've tried to recreate the renko chart on top of a regular candelstick chart but it doesn't seem to be counting correctly?